# IFRAME won't display 100% height in IE8, but fine in IE11 and Firefox

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, iframe, internet-explorer-8

I have a HTML page with an `iframe` in a `div`. The `iframe` height should be 100% of the available window height. This displays as expected in IE11 and Firefox, but in IE8 the `iframe` remains at a fixed size, regardless of the window size or the `iframe` content. When the browser is fullscreen, this is about 1/3 of the screen space.

Is this a quirk of IE8? How can I get the `iframe` to consume 100% height?

The browser is not in compatibility mode.

Cut-down example:

```css
html{
   height:100%;
}
body {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    height:100%; 
}

.row{
    display:table-row;
    height:100%; 
}

.iframeContainer{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

.iframeContainer iframe{
    width:100%; 
    height:100%; 
    border-style:solid !important; 
    border:2px; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="iframeContainer">
                    <iframe></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <style type=text/css>

        html,body{ padding:0;margin:0 }

        html{
           height:100%;
        }

        body {
            display:table;
            width:100%;
            height:100%; 
            position:relative;
            background-color:lightcoral;
        }

        .row{
            display:table-row;
            height:100%; 
            /*width:100%*/
        }

        .iframeContainer{
            /*height:100%;*/    /* use h+w instead of positioning below if outer (coral) frame is undesired */
            /*width:100%;*/
            /*display:table-cell;*/
            position:absolute;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0;margin:1em;
        }

        iframe{
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            border-style:solid !important; 
            border:2px; 
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="iframeContainer">
                <iframe src="about:blank" onload="this.contentDocument.body.style.backgroundColor='lavender'" frameborder=0></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

If I am understanding your purpose in setting body to display:table, it is for centering.  I am more comfortable using the position: technique with top,right,bottom,left=0 as the CSS 2.1 endorsed hack.  Whatever gets the job done, I guess.
Using the **table** trick with **IE8**, it needs the iframeContainer wrapper to be display:**table-cell**.  Else, as you explained, it fails to compute width+height and then the iframe w+h based on it doesn't work.  But even with the table-cell wrapper, it still makes the width+height difficult to manage, without slightly overflowing the viewport.  Here's an experiment with it:  [table-cell demo](https://googledrive.com/host/0B8BLd2qPPV7XfjRDTW54WGFuWGxIeTVnTXpXVVZ0ZG9TLXlzTkJBeFpTUkFhb283M2lqUXM/IE8-table-centering--table-cell.html)
Without totally changing your table strategy, we can still slip **positioning** into the style and get IE8 to work.  In doing so, it automatically sizes the box within the viewport without overflowing it.  In the above markup, I went a step further and framed the table with a 1em coral boundary.  (because it was easy at that point).  Here it is online:  [table-cell positioned](https://googledrive.com/host/0B8BLd2qPPV7XfjRDTW54WGFuWGxIeTVnTXpXVVZ0ZG9TLXlzTkJBeFpTUkFhb283M2lqUXM/IE8-table-centering--positioned.html)

Comment: Great answer! Thank you. The display:table is due to other stuff on the page that I cut out for simplicity. Adding display:table-cell to the iframeContainer (and then wrapping that in another div with display:table-row, to work with the stuff I chopped out) fixed it. The positioning tip helped too with getting the table to appear as desired.

Answer (score 2):

You can target only IE8 and less version IE browsers with CSS conditional comments.

> Method -1

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<style type="text/css">
* html, body { height: 100%; width:100%; margin:0; padding:0; }
iframe { padding-bottom: 0; height:100%; }

</style>
<![endif]-->
```

> Method -2

```
html, body{
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

> Method -3

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" frameborder="0" src="/chatbox/testb.html"></iframe>
```

> 100% height iframe with content

[image]

> Still 100% height iframe without content.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However when I plug any of these suggestions into the example code I still get the same problem of the IFRAME not consuming the remaining screen space in IE8.

Comment: @OwenPauling, I'm also using IE8 on my PC. Check my edited answer with Screenshots

Answer (score -1):

You could try

```
 height: 100vh;
```

This would make the iframe 100% of the viewport height

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it out but it didn't resolve the problem.

Comment: Sorry just read up on vh looks like its not supported to ie9.

I did a quick test and this seemed to work.

    <iframe src="http://www.bbc.co.uk/news" style="position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:999999;">
    Your browser doesn't support iframes
</iframe>